# OpenCV 2.4 error 0xc0000005 in Windows 7 64 bit

Tags: c++, windows, opencv, 64-bit

I am using CodeBlocks in my windows 7 64 bit and I use MinGw for my default c/c++ compiler.

Few days ago I need to use OpenCV, after I struggle a lot of error, I get unsolveable error like this :

[image: img]

[image: img2]

The sample code:

```
#include "cv.h"
#include "highgui.h"

int main( int argc, char** argv ) {
    IplImage* img = cvLoadImage( argv[1] );
    cvNamedWindow( "Example1", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    cvShowImage( "Example1", img );
    cvWaitKey(0);
    cvReleaseImage( &img );
    cvDestroyWindow( "Example1" );
}
```

I believe my linked & directory setting is correct. So please help me :) I am about to give up :(

Comment: You need to check whether cvLoadImage was successful before trying to display the image.

Comment: I have change to cvLoadImage("lena.jpg"); but still error. I put lena.jpg in same folder with my Main.exe

Comment: You need to check the result from cvLoadImage explicitly, e.g. `if (img == NULL) { perror("cvLoadImage failed"); exit(1); }`

Comment: A few hours ago, I just tried with Windows XP 32-bit in my virtual machine, and the same code & same setting CodeBlocks run perfectly. But I still curious why OpenCV 2.4 can't run in my 64-bit Windows 7 :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are doing everything correct in the code and the image, this can be a problem due to incompatible opencv binaries.

Please have a look at [a similar installation](http://seevisionc.blogspot.co.uk/2011/09/linux-like-installation-of-opencv-230.html) to compile and see if it works. I had a similar problem in my installation, which was fixed by compiling the binaries again.

Comment: Is that link is for 32-bit or 64-bit ? If 32-bit I has succeed, but for 64-bit I still have problem when I need to run my program (.exe)

Comment: this link is to compile 32-bit opencv binaries but I have always used it on a 64-bit version of Windows

Comment: i have tried, but I got error when I use CMake with MSYS when configuring. Did you try with Open CV 2.4 ?

Comment: I still can't run my C++ code :(
but no problem, now I am using OpenCV with Python and I run perfectly

thx for your answer, I think your answer is close enough, I will mark your answer as the correct one

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most probably a failure when loading the image. But you will only be certain if you check the return of `cvLoadImage()`:

```
IplImage* img = cvLoadImage( argv[1] );
if (!img)
{
    printf("!!! cvLoadImage failed\n");
}
```

The function fails if the image format is not supported, or if the image is not found in the specified location.

You application expects to load the file passed from the command line, so you better execute your application with: `Main.exe C:\some_img.png`

You can also hardcode the filename in your code:

```
IplImage* img = cvLoadImage("C:\\some_img.png");
if (!img)
{
    printf("!!! cvLoadImage failed\n");
}
```