# Error executing openCV aplication on WINDOWS 7

Tags: c++, eclipse, opencv

Im using eclipse with opencv and i have this simple project:

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  Mat im = imread(argc == 2 ? argv[1] : "lena.jpg", 1);
  if (im.empty())
  {
    cout << "Cannot open image!" << endl;
    return -1;
  }

  imshow("image", im);
  waitKey(0);

  return 0;
}
```

It apears to be correct acording to eclipse and it compiles just fine. But if i try to run it on debug mode from eclipse nothing happend and if i try to execute the .exe i get this error:

[image]

[image]

EDIT: These images are in spanish, but the error is exactly the same that the one in this post: [opencv 2.4 error in windows 7 64 bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11935422/opencv-2-4-error-in-windows-7-64-bit)

I am runing it on a virtual machine with windows 7 x86.

PS: Sry for my english!

Comment: How can the image help if its not english

Comment: u r rigth, here there is a post when the error its in english:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11935422/opencv-2-4-error-in-windows-7-64-bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a chance that when Eclipse runs your application it looks for `lena.jpg` in a directory where this file is not present.

Make sure you put the JPG in the same folder as your source files and also in the same folder as the **.exe**.

**Your code seems legit**, and this problem shouldn't be happening. The best way to figure out what's really going on is to **use the debugger and find out which of the calls trigger the error**.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i've checked that, the file is in the correct folder, besides if the file werent there i would get the output "Cannot open the image!".
I've tried to use the debugger but it does nothing.

Comment: Open the executable with [DLL Export Viewer](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/dll_export_viewer.html) and make sure you have all the DLLs needed to execute the application. Sometimes people forget to configure the **PATH** environment variable.

Comment: sry for my ignorance, but i've added two dll's to the folder where the  exe is (libopencv_core244.dll and libopencv_highgui244.dll) the reason why i added this is because the program said it needed them, now i have checked the dll's with the dll export viewer and those methods that i use (imread, imshow) are not there.
i've only added the mingw/bin to the path. Do i need to add anything else?

Comment: It's best to modify Windows PATH environment variable and add the correct PATH to all OpenCV DLLs. This might be your problem.

Comment: by doing that i will no longer need the dll's on the folder rigth?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Whenever you execute an application, it looks at  Windows PATH to figure out all the important directories of your system and then it tries to find all the needed DLLs from those directories defined in the PATH. You might have to reboot your system after modifying the PATH.

Comment: i've added the dll's folder to the path, and i have removed the dlls from the exe's folder (it does not ask for them anymore like u said) but the problem persist. I'll do try to do this on another pc and if it works i'll work there (i know thats not how it should be done but i dont know what else can i do).

Comment: Use **DLL Export Viewer** to check that your application has access to all the DLLs it neeeds! I've seen this stuff happen in the past, couldn't fix it, and for some reason only the C interface of OpenCV worked (cvLoadImage, IplImage, etc). As a last alternative, install the most recent version of OpenCV. Make sure to remove the previous versions to avoid conflict.

Comment: i've tried on the other pc and it works. about the version of opnecv i have the latest version.. i'll try installing the previous one.. Thanks for all the help mate.